Mutex causing "Segmentation fault" in kotlin multiplatform
While trying to synchronize data for my Entity abstract class I found out about Mutex, it is great because it is supposed to work on every target I want to develop to but every time I create implementation of lock (other ways to synchronize) or Mutex itself then after compiling I'm getting Segmentation fault, that suggest that I'm trying to access memory outside my application but I tested this with and without synchronization and every time application crashes when I create Lock or Mutex. Here some example code:
*** Entity.kt ***

import interfaces.Effect
import datas.Stats
import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.Mutex
import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.withLock

abstract class Entity(private val baseStats: Stats) {
    private val _activeEffects: MutableList<Effect> = mutableListOf()
    val activeEffects: List<Effect> get() = _activeEffects
    var dirtyFlag = true
        private set
    private var calculatedStats = stats
    private var lock = Mutex()
    
    val stats: Stats
        get() {
            if (dirtyFlag && lock.tryLock()) {
                var tempStats = baseStats
                activeEffects.forEach {
                    tempStats += it.change
                }
                calculatedStats = tempStats
                dirtyFlag = !dirtyFlag
                lock.unlock()
                return tempStats
            } else {
                return calculatedStats
            }
        }
    
    suspend fun applyEffect(effect: Effect) {
        lock.withLock(lock) {
            _activeEffects.add(effect)
            dirtyFlag = true
        }
    }
    
    suspend fun removeEffect(effect: Effect) {
        lock.withLock(lock) {
            _activeEffects.remove(effect)
        }
    }
}

*** Character.kt ***

import abstracts.Entity
import datas.Stats

data class Character(
    private val baseStats: Stats
): Entity(baseStats) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Base stats: $baseStats\nCurrent stats: $stats"
    }
}

*** Main.kt ***

import datas.Stats
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import models.Character
import models.DamageEffect


fun main() {
    try {
        val character = Character(Stats(10, 10))
        runBlocking {
            character.applyEffect(DamageEffect(5, 5))
        }
        println(character.stats)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

*** Stats.kt ***

data class Stats(
    val hp: Int = 0, // health points
    val mp: Int = 0, // mind points
) {

    operator fun plus(other: Stats) = Stats(
        hp + other.hp,
        mp + other.mp
    )
}

I really have no idea why this thing happens because like I said if private var lock = Mutex() is commented out and all lock calls deleted then everything works.
I even tried to move Mutex initialization outside Entity by making it abstract and initializing it inside Character data class but nothing changed.
